# Combining columns of two different datasets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that needs to always return the same dataset structure, columns a, b, c and d.
It needs to return a UNION ALL from more than one datasource, including other UDF:s.

Let's say I have another function (myOtherUDF) that returns column a and b.
I also have a table (myTable) with the column names a, b, c and d.
What I want to do is to UNION ALL on myOtherUDF and myTable in a way that the columns c and d are added to myOtherUDF.

i.e. I want this to work although myOtherUDF lacks the columns c and d:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myUDF (@param INT)  
RETURNS @tbl TABLE   
(  
    a int NOT NULL,  
    b int NOT NULL,
    c int NOT NULL,
    d int NOT NULL
)  
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    UNION ALL // this will obviously not work
    SELECT * FROM myOtherUDF(@param)
    RETURN
END
```

I cannot use a process to preload a table and I cannot use a view since I need the parameter @param.

Comment: Of course I meant that I cannot use a stored procedure, not a process. Sorry for the typeo.

Comment: the columns c & d could be replaced by cero for the time being, as long as I can get the return set right

Comment: I'm using inline sql from python to build the union statement from a web application. It would be difficult to specify the column names explicitly for this case

Comment: Any reason why you are using multi statement and not inline table functions

Comment: "I'm using inline sql from python to build the union statement" - how? You've shown it within a function? Surely you aren't creating the function from Python? You need to clarify exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly list your columns - which is best practice - you immediately solve this problem, well after adding defaults for `c` and `d` from `myOtherUDF`;

```
INSERT INTO @tbl (a, b, c, d)
    SELECT a, b, c, d
    FROM myTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a, b, 0, 0
    FROM myOtherUDF(@param);

RETURN;
```

To be clear you should pretty much never `select *` and never `insert into table` without listing the columns. It saves so many issues down the line.

And for performance reasons its nearly always better to use an inline table valued function e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myUDF
(
    @param INT
)  
RETURNS TABLE   
RETURN
    SELECT a, b, c, d
    FROM myTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a, b, 0, 0
    FROM myOtherUDF(@param);
```

Comment: @JonasWidmark Right... so? How does that affect my answer?

Comment: The structure of the dataset I need will allways be defined by myTable but the number of columns will vary over time.
What i really want to do is to build a query statement as a UNION (or similar) of multiple sources although some of the e.g. myOtherODF only overlaps 2 of the four columns.
I thought a UDF could be a solution but it is not necessary. Building (and default setting) all columns (there are many) in the query I build in python would be tedious and I would much rather a solution in the db.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the last comment by misstake before editing it fully.

Comment: Databases are not like code, if you make schema changes you can expect to have to update your code somewhere. SQL is not designed for the type of generic handling you might do in Python or C#. So based on what I understand you want, encapsulating this logic within a function as I have shown you is probably the cleanest way to handle it. Yes, if you change the schema you will have to update the function to reflect that, but thats all, its all on one place and you can see it there. There are no magic bullets for handling future database schema changes I am afraid, you need systems to handle.